# Setting up unsubscribe page

Tags: newsletter

Currently using CiviCRM 4.1.11 and Joomla 4.6.8.

We're looking to set up a newsletter and that will require an unsubscribe page. I gather that you use a token to set up an unsubscribe link but does that actually set up the unsubscribe page or do I need another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the token {action.unsubscribeUrl} CiviCRM will create a personalised link in the mailing. Users are be able to click on it and will be redirected to a page generated by CiviCRM.

In addition, they will get a confirmation via email. If this standard workflow is sufficient for you you don't need to do anything else.

You can try it out yourself: Just send out a mailing including you and use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a profile that includes the field Contacts > Groups.

Then send the link to that profile in edit mode, in Joomla the url will look like: http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/edit&gid=1&reset=1

This url is the modified **Create Mode** (changing create to edit). To see how to get that [click here](https://aghstrategies.com/content/civicrm-profiles-beyond-contributions-registrations-part-1#Introduction)

The user will need to be logged in to make changes. You can send a token in an email by adding &id={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum} to the url.